# Building a nine - region cluster chart with Tooltip to display labels associated with 2D points

Tags: plotting, cluster-analysis

I'm attempting to build a nine-region cluster chart using Tooltip to display labels associated with 2-D points also displayed on it.  I do NOT want to use "FindClusters".  I want to design my own cluster chart as explained below.  The following mock data is made-up of 2-D points where each points have a label-identifier called a "NAICS" code (NAICS stands for "North American Industry
Classification System").

```
mockdataWithNAICS = {{"29-1141", 186, 112}, {"41-2031", 123, 92}, {"41-1011", 65, 404}, {"43-4051", 108, 646}, {"31-1014", 643, 246},
        {"49-9071", 356, 363}, {"43-1011", 543, 381}, {"43-5081", 268, 674}, {"53-3032", 416, 653}, {"37-3011", 514, 428}, {"37-2012", 501, 58},
        {"33-9032", 441, 598}, {"35-2014", 633, 138}, {"29-2061", 414, 590}, {"53-3033", 98, 155}, {"35-3031", 179, 431}, {"49-3023", 93, 623},
        {"35-3021", 37, 578}, {"41-2011", 256, 237}, {"37-2011", 302, 50}, {"47-1011", 518, 2}, {"11-9111", 313, 294}, {"31-9092", 698, 136},
        {"43-3031", 608, 610}, {"43-6013", 562, 515}, {"13-2011", 415, 327}, {"21-1093", 191, 72}, {"41-4012", 212, 92}, {"41-3031", 546, 418},
        {"31-1011", 591, 49}, {"47-2031", 405, 526}, {"41-3021", 191, 297}, {"15-1151", 442, 445}, {"43-6011", 118, 185}, {"49-1011", 472, 402},
        {"53-7062", 348, 552}, {"43-4171", 409, 396}, {"43-6014", 348, 247}, {"53-1031", 629, 59}, {"47-2061", 589, 534}, {"27-1026", 22, 377},
        {"29-1069", 445, 74}, {"49-9021", 647, 539}, {"43-9061", 25, 543}, {"11-1021", 19, 165}, {"41-1012", 482, 199}, {"29-1062", 1, 68},
        {"43-4081", 217, 112}, {"41-3099", 663, 66}, {"11-3031", 329, 392}, {"53-7061", 357, 515}, {"35-2021", 488, 245}, {"31-9091", 318, 679},
        {"51-1011", 650, 349}, {"11-9051", 38, 145}, {"53-3031", 166, 691}, {"39-9021", 561, 127}, {"39-5012", 665, 362}, {"47-2111", 397, 532},
        {"43-3071", 326, 271}, {"29-2034", 361, 450}, {"35-9011", 12, 366}, {"29-1123", 16, 211}, {"15-1142",162, 662}, {"11-2021", 520, 164},
        {"29-2031", 339, 619}, {"25-2011", 263, 564}, {"41-4011", 551, 301}, {"29-2055", 76, 549}, {"29-2052", 285, 640}, {"13-2072", 370, 542},
        {"35-2012", 512, 547}, {"11-2022", 130, 154}, {"15-1132", 188, 274}, {"13-2052", 338, 587}, {"15-1199", 455, 5}, {"35-9031", 595, 472},
        {"17-2051", 648, 481}, {"11-9199", 430, 189}, {"39-3091", 29, 396}, {"47-2152", 412, 342}, {"29-1122", 582, 20}, {"11-9141", 276, 4},
        {"25-2021", 666, 617}, {"15-1134", 236, 334}, {"37-1011", 407, 664}, {"29-1063", 260, 278}, {"49-3031", 161, 354}, {"41-9022", 185, 144},
        {"41-9041", 551, 628}, {"25-2031", 529, 505}, {"29-2071", 548, 296}, {"29-1127", 373, 124}, {"21-1023", 473, 71}, {"29-1067", 489, 569},
        {"29-1071", 539, 277}, {"11-3121", 390, 348}, {"11-9021", 634, 20}, {"53-3041", 589, 258}, {"49-3021", 47, 206}};

L = Length[mockdataWithNAICS];
counter = Range[L];
counter = Range[L];
mock2Dvalues = {mockdataWithNAICS[[#]][[2]], mockdataWithNAICS[[#]][[3]]} & /@ counter
```

The following measurements are necessary to build a grid :

```
minx = Round[Min[Table[{mock2Dvalues[[i]][[1]]}, {i, 1, L}]]];
maxx = Round[Max[Table[{mock2Dvalues[[i]][[1]]}, {i, 1, L}]]];

dx = Round[Subdivide[minx, maxx, 3]];

miny = Round[Min[Table[{mock2Dvalues[[i]][[2]]}, {i, 1, L}]]];

maxy = Round[Max[Table[{mock2Dvalues[[i]][[2]]}, {i, 1, L}]]];

dy = Round[Subdivide[miny, maxy, 3]];

gridpts = Tuples[{dx, dy}];
```

The following plot will allow you to visualize the grid and all the data points :

```
plt1 = ListPlot[gridpts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  GridLines -> {dx, dy}, Epilog :> {Blue, Point[mock2Dvalues]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The purpose of the following plot is to allow you to display the grid
points with the aid of Tooltip to define the following nine regions :

```
plt2 = ListPlot[Tooltip[gridpts], Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  GridLines -> {dx, dy}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here we define the nine cluster regions.  We assign colors to the region names as a "mnemonic device" to associate the 2-D points with the regions that they belong-to, according to color.  The colors are arbitrary :

```
    magentaregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[1]], gridpts[[6]]]

    orangeregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[5]], gridpts[[10]]]

    cyanregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[9]], gridpts[[14]]]

    redregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[2]], gridpts[[7]]]

    blueregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[6]], gridpts[[11]]]

    greenregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[10]], gridpts[[15]]]

    lightgrayregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[3]], gridpts[[8]]]

    yellowregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[7]], gridpts[[12]]]

    blackregion = Rectangle[gridpts[[11]], gridpts[[16]]]
```

Here we disburse the points according to the regions where they belong to :

```
magentapts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] magentaregion &]

orangepts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] orangeregion &]

cyanpts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] cyanregion &]

redpts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] redregion &]

bluepts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] blueregion &]

greenpts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] greenregion &]

lightgraypts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] lightgrayregion &]

yellowpts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] yellowregion &]

blackpts = Select[mock2Dvalues, # \[Element] blackregion &]
```

The following plots are necessary to build the final chart below :

```
plt3 = ListPlot[magentapts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Magenta, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt4 = ListPlot[orangepts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt5 = ListPlot[cyanpts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Cyan, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt6 = ListPlot[redpts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt7 = ListPlot[bluepts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt8 = ListPlot[greenpts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt9 = ListPlot[lightgraypts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> LightGray, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt10 = ListPlot[yellowpts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

plt11 = ListPlot[blackpts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   GridLines -> {dx, dy}, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
```

This plot shows the nine-region cluster chart with the points colored by the region that they belong to :

```
finalchart = Show[{plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7, plt8, plt9, plt10, plt11}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally; we establish an association between the NAICS codes and their 2 - D points as follows:

```
mockdataWithNAICSlabels = 
  Association[#[[1]] -> #[[2 ;; 3]] & /@ mockdataWithNAICS];

Dataset[mockdataWithNAICSlabels]
```

My question is: How can I associate the NAICS codes to their respective points BY COLORED REGION, so that if I use Tooltip; the NAICS codes will be displayed for each point in the above finalchart?  Thank you!

Comment: Gilmar, a gentle reminder (if I may) re the comments [following this post of yours re your previous questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203729/125)

Comment: Dear Carl @kglr: I read your answer at the time and accepted your answer.  I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me?  That was a different topic (and post) altogether.  Please, elaborate if you must.

Comment: @kglr  How do I accept answers retro-actively?  When I review my old posts there are no green check marks to be checked any more.  As I made clear before; I learned about pressing the green check mark recently and I have done it ever since.  I have NOT left the green check marks unchecked intentionally or with malice.  Thank you.

Comment: @Carl Lange How do I accept answers retro-actively? When I review my old posts there are no green check marks to be checked any more. As I made clear before; I learned about pressing the green check mark recently and I have done it ever since. I have NOT left the green check marks unchecked intentionally or with malice. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Gilmar. This is strange; you should be able accept/unaccept anytime. Perhaps this calls for  developer/moderator attention to fix whatever is wrong with the pages you are seeing.

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi It might be that if you have unaccepted an answer, you cannot accept that answer again unless it has been edited. So it may be that for such a question, you don't see a checkmark. But you should still be able to see it for other questions as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
colors = {Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Red, Blue, Green, LightGray, Yellow, Black};

tooltips = {##2} -> Tooltip[{##2}, #] & @@@ mockdataWithNAICS;

{dx, dy} = Round[Subdivide[##, 3]] & @@@ (Round[MinMax@#] & /@ 
          Transpose[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, {2, 3}]]]);
```

You can use [`BinLists`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinLists.html) with `{dx}` and `{dy}` as horizontal and vertical bin delimiters to group the data into bins:

```
binlists = Join @@ BinLists[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, {2, 3}]], {dx}, { dy}];
```

and use a single `ListPlot` to plot all groups:

```
ListPlot[binlists /. tooltips, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> colors,
  GridLines -> {dx, dy}, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
  Axes -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 710}, {-10, 710}}]
```

[image]

With a minor modification in `tooltips`, you can also use [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html)

```
tooltips2 = {##2} -> Tooltip[{##2, 1}, #] & @@@ mockdataWithNAICS;

BubbleChart[binlists /. tooltips2, 
  Frame -> True, 
  ChartStyle -> colors,
  GridLines -> {dx, dy}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  BubbleSizes -> {.02, .02},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 710}, {-10, 710}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way to bin the data using [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html):

```
bincenters = Tuples[MovingAverage[#, 2] & /@ {dx, dy}];
nF = Nearest[bincenters];
binlists2 = GatherBy[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, {2, 3}]], nF];
```

Using `binlists2` with `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[binlists2 /. tooltips, 
 Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {dx, dy}, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 PlotStyle -> colors, 
 Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 710}, {-10, 710}}]
```

[image]

and with `BubbleChart`:

```
BubbleChart[binlists2 /. tooltips2, 
  Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> {dx, dy}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  BubbleSizes -> {.02, .02}, 
  ChartStyle -> colors, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 710}, {-10, 710}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @kglr; I accept your answer (and your update) !  I love the way how you were able to condense the whole process.  You will be saving me a lot of work every month! I pressed the checkmark (which went from gray color to green).  I think that it should be the other way around (from green to gray) but, the important thing is that it works (I hope).  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi. Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this has the intended functionality, with simplified code.

```
minx = Round[Min[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, 2]]]];
maxx = Round[Max[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, 2]]]];
dx = Round[Subdivide[minx, maxx, 3]];

miny = Round[Min[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, 3]]]];
maxy = Round[Max[mockdataWithNAICS[[All, 3]]]];
dy = Round[Subdivide[miny, maxy, 3]];

gridpts = Tuples[{dx, dy}];

regions = {
   Rectangle[gridpts[[1]], gridpts[[6]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[5]], gridpts[[10]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[9]], gridpts[[14]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[2]], gridpts[[7]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[6]], gridpts[[11]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[10]], gridpts[[15]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[3]], gridpts[[8]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[7]], gridpts[[12]]],
   Rectangle[gridpts[[11]], gridpts[[16]]]};

(* Updated per GilmarRodriguezPierluissi's suggestion, to work with data sets that have empty regions *)
pts = Cases[Table[Select[mockdataWithNAICS, #[[{2, 3}]] \[Element] r &], {r, 
     regions}], Except[{}]];

colors = {Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Red, Blue, Green, LightGray, Yellow, 
   Black};

ListPlot[Table[Tooltip[#[[{2, 3}]], #[[1]]] & /@ p, {p, pts}], 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> colors, GridLines -> {dx, dy}, 
 PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MelaGo for your valuable help!  I wish I could accept you answer as well but, we are only allowed to accept one answer.  Question; what software did you use to build the "gif movie", showing the Tooltip sweeping the points?  Thanks again!

Comment: For other data sets containing points not as nicely distributed as my mock data set above; using:                                                                  pts = Cases[
   Table[Select[mockdataWithNAICS, #[[{2, 3}]] \[Element] r &], {r, 
     regions}], Except[{}]];                                                                 accounts for situations in which there are no points in a region.

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi You're welcome. I used the free version of Active Presenter to screenshot a movie. I couldn't figure out how to directly make an animated gif, so I used `mov=Import["file.avi","Animation"]; Export["file.gif",mov,"AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity]` in Mathematica. Probably not the best solution...

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi Good point about the empty regions - I will update the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @MelaGo for your tip about the Active Presenter (i.e.; "gif maker") !  Also; I just posted the following follow up question for the Stack Exchange Forum via: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206795/building-a-nine-region-cluster-chart-but-getting-inaccurate-plot-legend-when